# Creating a nested dictionary from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list `Final_Bioteck` whose first 5 enteries looks like this:

```
['PBYI', 'DRRX', 'FBIO', 'CAPR', 'KDMN']
```

I'm trying to create a nested dictionary with the first layer being the letters of the alphabet and the second layer being an element from the above list.
I'm trying to create an indexed dictionary.

I attempted to do so with the code below:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase

Bioteck_dict ={}
for letter in ascii_uppercase:
    for stock in Final_Bioteck:
        if stock.startswith(letter):
            try:
                Bioteck_dict[letter].update(stock)
            except KeyError:
                Bioteck_dict[letter] = stock
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
'str' object has no attribute 'update'
```

Desired output is something like this:

Bioteck_dict

```
{A:
B:
C: 'CAPR':{}
D:  'DRRX':{}
E:
F:
```

or even this:

```
 {A:
    B:
    C: 'CAPR'
    D:  'DRRX'
    E:
    F:   'FBIO':


              }
```

Comment: Could you provide the desired output for the given input?

Comment: Sorry, just added at the moment.

Comment: How should this be different if you have, say, `'FBIO'` and also `'FACE'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.update()` is a method for dicts, and you're calling it on a string.  This is a way of doing what you appear to want:

```
Final_Bioteck = ['PBYI', 'DRRX', 'FBIO', 'CAPR', 'KDMN']
Bioteck_dict = {}
for stock in Final_Bioteck:
    Bioteck_dict.setdefault(stock[0], {})[stock] = {}
```

Following the update to your question, it seems like you want letters that have no associated stocks to nonetheless be explicitly represented in the `dict` as empty containers.  It's questionable whether you really need that (most things you would subsequently want to do will involve just iterating over what *is* in the `dict`) but you can get that effect in one of two ways:

EITHER:

```
Final_Bioteck = ['PBYI', 'DRRX', 'FBIO', 'CAPR', 'KDMN']
from collections import defaultdict
Bioteck_dict = defaultdict(dict)   # now you can look up any letter (or any key at all) and receive the empty dict, even if there was no entry there before
for stock in Final_Bioteck:
    Bioteck_dict[stock[0]][stock] = {}
```

OR:

```
Final_Bioteck = ['PBYI', 'DRRX', 'FBIO', 'CAPR', 'KDMN']
Bioteck_dict = {letter:{} for letter in 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'}
for stock in Final_Bioteck:
    Bioteck_dict[stock[0]][stock] = {}
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be the best answer and closest to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're assigning each dict value as a string, not a dict. It needs to start off as a dict so you can update it. `'FBIO'.update(blah)` makes no sense. Additionally, you probably want a dict of lists, rather than a dict of dicts—what would the key be, after all?

```
from collections import defaultdict

Bioteck_dict = defaultdict(list)  # Or `set`, if unique and unordered.
for stock in Final_Bioteck:
    Bioteck_dict[stock[0]].append(stock)
```

The result is:

```
{'C': ['CAPR'], 'D': ['DRRX'], 'F': ['FBIO'], 'K': ['KDMN'], 'P': ['PBYI']}
```

Answer (score 1):

This one is a bit more akin to your logic:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase

stocks = ['PBYI', 'DRRX', 'FBIO', 'CAPR', 'KDMN']
d = {}
for letter in ascii_uppercase:
    d[letter] = {}
    for stock in stocks:
        if stock.startswith(letter):
            d[letter][stock] = {}

print d
```

That returns:

```
{'A': {}, 'C': {'CAPR': {}}, 'B': {}, 'E': {}, 'D': {'DRRX': {}}, 'G': {}, 'F': {'FBIO': {}}, 'I': {}, 'H': {}, 'K': {'KDMN': {}}, 'J': {}, 'M': {}, 'L': {}, 'O': {}, 'N': {}, 'Q': {}, 'P': {'PBYI': {}}, 'S': {}, 'R': {}, 'U': {}, 'T': {}, 'W': {}, 'V': {}, 'Y': {}, 'X': {}, 'Z': {}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using dict comprehension, if unique records.

```
l = ['PBYI', 'DRRX', 'FBIO', 'CAPR', 'KDMN']
d = { i[0]:i for i in l}
pprint(d)
```

Output:

```
{'C': 'CAPR', 'D': 'DRRX', 'F': 'FBIO', 'K': 'KDMN', 'P': 'PBYI'}
```

Use defaultdict if multiple records.

```
l = ['PBYI', 'DRRX', 'FBIO', 'CAPR', 'KDMN', 'DUMMY','CAT','COLD']
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for i in l:
    d[i[0]].append(i)
pprint(d)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
            {'C': ['CAPR', 'CAT', 'COLD'],
             'D': ['DRRX', 'DUMMY'],
             'F': ['FBIO'],
             'K': ['KDMN'],
             'P': ['PBYI']})
```